Why is an Autocallable dependent on the vol-of-vol and forward smile?
I am trying to build an intuition on why an Autocallable is dependent on the vol-of-vol and forward smile, justifying why we should use LSV model. I have a simple intuition for the latter: I am initially long vega so if AC event I have to buy-back some vega to unwind the vega hedge. For exemple in case of a 3Y AC, if in 1 year there is an autocall event I have to unwind some vega on a smile that is different (for the same options). So it makes the AC more expensive using LSV compared to LV.
Can you please refer me to some paper/books to get a better intuition, especially on the vol-of-vol or explain it clearly?
